# Can I use navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia In Android/IOS Webview?

Tags: javascript, webview, camera

I have some problem in using web-api in Android/IOS's native apps

In webview, I render a html, and I want use camera for taking photos, I search for web api and found a method, that is

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
  .then(function(mediaStream) { ... })
  .catch(function(error) { ... })
```

This api works well in PC browers, but in webview, it doesn't work, why?

Is there any other way to use camera by JS in webview(not by Android/IOS native apis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that currently on iOS you cannot use `getUserMedia` in a `WebView`.  I believe it does work on Android OS.

This may change in the future, though!

See also:  https://github.com/BasqueVoIPMafia/cordova-plugin-iosrtc/issues/250#issuecomment-336240953

Comment: Thank you very much