# How to access camera through webview in react native

Tags: react-native, webview

I am trying to load a webpage (that must access the camera) on WebView using react native .But i can't access the camera through webview in react native android app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to use the Camera from within a WebView on iOS,
just Use

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} PhotoLibrary Usage</string>
```

steps are given below in images:

Open info.plist with Source Code

[image]

Paste the above code here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is possible to use `getUserMedia` from within a WebView on Android, but not iOS - [can-i-use-navigator-mediadevices-getusermedia-in-android-ios-webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46709949/can-i-use-navigator-mediadevices-getusermedia-in-android-ios-webview)

Check this out for a way to do it in iOS (but it looks like it will require a custom iOS module) - [access-camera-from-uiwebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915881/access-camera-from-uiwebview)